# Angular components as self validating formControls

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this, I assume there should be. Basically I have a component I want to treat as a standalone form control. This control will always have some sort of special validation attached and I would like it to bubble up to the form whenever the component is used.

I've attached a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eiFwJzqeupS5I02C6Zgt?p=preview). Is there a way to for the form to be marked invalid if the component/formControl is invalid? I know I could add the validator to the form itself, but I would like to make things easy and more predictable for future use of this component. I'm also open to better ideas of doing this.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <my-component-control formControlName="myComponent"></my-component-control>
    </form>
    <div>Form Value: {{form.value | json}}</div>
    <div>Form Valid: {{form.valid}}</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      myComponent: ''
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component-control',
  template: `
    <div>Control Errors: {{control.errors | json}}</div>
    <input [formControl]="control">
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyComponentComponent),
    }
  ]
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  control: FormControl;

  onChange: any = () => { };
  onTouched: any = () => { };

  constructor() {
    this.control = new FormControl('', (control) => {
      return control.value ? null : {shouldHaveSomething: true};
    });
    this.control.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      this.onChange(value);
      this.onTouched();
    });
  }

  writeValue (obj: any): void {
    this.control.setValue(obj);
  }
  registerOnChange (fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched (fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
}
```

Comment: take a look at angular/material's approach. They separate the form fields from the `mat-error` directive: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/0834a31d03ae6707633e01d43200703840b70c5a/src/lib/form-field/error.ts

Comment: @masterfloda Thanks for the info. I have something similar for showing the control has an error itself, but what I really need it the control to influence the `valid` property on the form itself as I don't want `ngSubmit` to be triggerable until the form is actually valid. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, but I would not make validation part of the field component. Just use Angular's form validation https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#reactive-form-validation . Or do I somehow miss the point here?

Comment: I *can* do that. I was just trying to avoid it because this component it going to be used in several places and I know one of these days I'm going to forget to add the validator to the form. I was just hoping there was a way to make it ALWAYS validate for this component.

Comment: That makes sense... I haven't tried this myself, so it's just a guess, but you could use the `setError` method of `FormControl` https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValue

Comment: Sadly, I tried this before, and just tried it again in the plunker to verify. Calling `setErrors` on the `MyComponentComponent` does not bubble up to the form. I imagine it's because the formControl in the component is not directly associate with the formControl specified in the parent form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be using [setValidators](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValidators) method on host `AbstractControl`

To do so I'm going to get reference to `AbstractControl` through `NgControl`. We can't just inject `NgControl` in constructor because we'll get issue with instantiating cyclic dependency.

```
constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  ...     
}

ngOnInit() {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    const hostControl = this.injector.get(NgControl, null);
    if (hostControl) {
      hostControl.control.setValidators(this.control.validator);
      hostControl.control.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
  }); 
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/m3J4yHg3ylDfxbYfKl0I?open=app%2Fcustom-control.ts&layout=1)**

Comment: This is basically exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.